# SAS Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test

Tags: statistics, sas

I'm running the following to check whether there's any difference between the median of the variable day1TotalStake across a series of day1AverageReturnQuartiles with the following statement:

```
proc npar1way data = hsb2a wilcoxon;
  class day1AverageReturnQuartile;
  var day1TotalStake;
run;
```

SAS will only output a Kruskal-Wallace statistic, however. It does report rank sums for each Quartile, but no overall statistic.

Should I be calling some other function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code and it gave me the "Wilcoxon Two-Sample test" statistic (sum of ranks). If [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon_test) and my undergrad non-parametrics course are serving me, the "U" statistic can be easily derived from this value by subtracting a constant. If you're looking for assistance with that, you may want to ask at https://stats.stackexchange.com/.